# I'm trying to select multiple elements with the queryselectorall but it seems not working and i don't know why

Tags: javascript, html, function, queryselector

I've tried the queryselector and it selects the first element. I've also tried this using a for loop but it didn't worked too, maybe I have been doing it wrong. Can someone help me with this?

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="list">
      <div id="item1" class="bttn">Apple</div>
      <div id="item2" class="bttn">Mango</div>
      <div id="item3" class="bttn">Banana</div>
      <div id="item4" class="bttn">Kiwi</div>
    </div>
<style> 

.bttn{
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
} 

</style>
<script>
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".bttn");
  console.log(list);
  list.onclick = function(){
    this.style.background = "red";
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code with for Loop. querySelectorAll returns a collection, you will have to attach individually.

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop through your collection and apply the click listener to each matching element, and access that element inside the handler with `event.target`

```
<script>
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".bttn");
  console.log(list);
  list.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.style.background = "red";
  }))
</script>
```

You could abstract out the listener function if desired

```
<script>
  let list = document.querySelectorAll(".bttn");
  const onBttnClick = (e) => {
    e.target.style.background = "red";
  }
  list.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', onBttnClick))
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the onlick event listener to the Dom Element array.
You've to iterate over the array and assign the event listener to each element.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="list">
      <div id="item1" class="bttn">Apple</div>
      <div id="item2" class="bttn">Mango</div>
      <div id="item3" class="bttn">Banana</div>
      <div id="item4" class="bttn">Kiwi</div>
    </div>
<style> 

.bttn{
  display: flex;
  cursor: pointer;
} 

</style>
<script>
  var list = document.querySelectorAll(".bttn");
  console.log(list);
  list.forEach(function(e){
     e.addEventListener('click', function(){
        this.style.background = "red";
      }, false);
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```